# Include external js and css file in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

It's Bala. I am having Issue to add External css and js file in html.

The below code does not work:

```js
$( window ).ready(function() {
    var wHeight = $(window).height();
    $('.slide')
      .height(wHeight)
      .scrollie({
        scrollOffset : -50,
        scrollingInView : function(elem) {

          var bgColor = elem.data('background');

          $('body').css('background-color', bgColor);
        }
      });

  });
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box }

body {
  font-family: 'Coming Soon', cursive;
  transition: background 1s ease;
  background: #3498db;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

p {
  color: #ecf0f1;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;

}

span {
  clear: both;
  font-size: .7em;
  color: #bdc3c7;
}

a {
  color: #c0392b;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.slide {

  .inside {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 3em;

    p {
      display: table-cell;
      width: 100%;
      clear: both;
      vertical-align: middle; 
      text-align: center; 
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="2.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please create code snippet in your question

Comment: No, I actually Closed..

Comment: i've created the snippet. Seems like there is no scrollie function: `"message": "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).height(...).scrollie is not a function",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",`

Answer (score 0):

Try it with this one. Replace the `link` tag with this one:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="2.css" />
```

But it also depends where your `css` file is stored. I'm not sure why your posting the JS part. Maybe you can explain?

Comment: No, It's Not Working

Answer (score 0):

Use `scroll` function:

```js
$( window ).ready(function() {
    var wHeight = $(window).height();
    $('.slide')
      .height(wHeight)
      .scroll({
        scrollOffset : -50,
        scrollingInView : function(elem) {

          var bgColor = elem.data('background');

          $('body').css('background-color', bgColor);
        }
      });

  });
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box }

body {
  font-family: 'Coming Soon', cursive;
  transition: background 1s ease;
  background: #3498db;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

p {
  color: #ecf0f1;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;

}

span {
  clear: both;
  font-size: .7em;
  color: #bdc3c7;
}

a {
  color: #c0392b;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.slide {

  .inside {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 3em;

    p {
      display: table-cell;
      width: 100%;
      clear: both;
      vertical-align: middle; 
      text-align: center; 
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="2.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="slide"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You add two lines to your HTML file

This line is added between  tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

This line is added between the  tag and just above the close

```
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```